# R studio "pavo" package: can i plot two data in the same tetrahedral colorspace using function "tcsplot"?

Tags: r

I'm using the "pavo" package in R studio to create a tetrahedral colorspace plot using function "tcsplot". I want to ask that how can I write to combine two respectively data in the same tetrahedral colorspace plot

```
tcsplot(data1, 
    size = 0.01, 
    alpha = 1, 
    col = "green", 
    vertexsize = 0.02, 
    achro = TRUE, 
    achrosize = 0.01, 
    achrocol = "grey", 
    lwd = 1, 
    lcol = "lightgrey", 
    new = FALSE, 
    hspin = FALSE, 
    vspin = FALSE, 
    floor = F, 
    grid = TRUE, 
    fill = TRUE
)
```

[image]

by the way, how can I output this plot format?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add points to a plot produced by [`tcsplot()`](http://rafaelmaia.net/pavo/reference/tcsplot.html), you can use [`tcspoints()`](http://rafaelmaia.net/pavo/reference/tcsplot.html) (similar to base R `plot()` and `points()` functions):

```r
library(pavo)

data(sicalis)
data(flowers)

vis_sicalis <- vismodel(sicalis)
vis_flowers <- vismodel(flowers)

tcs_sicalis <- colspace(vis_sicalis)
tcs_flowers <- colspace(vis_flowers)

tcsplot(tcs_sicalis, col = "green")
tcspoints(tcs_flowers, col = "red")
```